# Should Citizen Patrol apply to all flags?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges, flagging-badges

I got a load of Citizen Patrol badges this morning, which is nice.

I know the rules have changed, but I got it on Cooking SE, and I'm pretty certain that I've never flagged anything there.

Sorry if I'm wrong (I don't think I've got any way of checking).

Comment: I just got one this morning here as well. But I also don't think I have flagged anything meta.

Comment: Are you sure? Nothing? No questions, answers, comments, chat messages? Not even for CW or so?

Comment: I've only got one on SO and MSO.

Comment: Perhaps... did you perchance mark anything through `/review`?

Comment: I got the same thing. A citizen patrol badge (on SO). And I never flagged a post, a comment... Anything.

Comment: I just got one on SO and MSO.

Comment: ...and Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: Just adding to the list... http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1146/citizen-patrol-bug

Comment: I just got one today too on SO and I've never flagged...

Comment: @Jeff, I don't *think* I've ever mod flagged on cooking either, have you guys checked?

Comment: @benjol the database never lies

Comment: @Benjol you flagged [this Cooking post](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/262/chili-benefits-and-harm) on 2011-01-17.  You didn't like the tags :)

Comment: @Leslie you flagged [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240777/batch-file-virus-wont-work-in-windows-7) on 2010-07-13 with your concerns about the asker writing a virus.  The question has since been deleted.

Comment: @Jeff, I wasn't doubting the database, I was just checking that someone had actually looked. @Jarrod, ok, so much for my memory :)

Comment: @Jarrod, thank you for checking. I do kind of vaguely remember that now.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff finally clears this up [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1146/citizen-patrol-bug/1148#1148):

> Citizen Patrol has been extended to all mod flags, so if you have ever mod flagged, you will now get it.
>
> Jeff Atwood♦

Now *mod* flagging I *have* done.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never mod flagged on cooking either...

Comment: I have never (intentionally) flagged anything anywhere.