# Citizen Patrol Badges Awarded Without Any Flag Post

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are you *sure* Citizen Patrol is fixed right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78797/are-you-sure-citizen-patrol-is-fixed-right)

I have recently earned the badge **Citizen Patrol**. But there is not any single post flag by me.

Why have I received this badge?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have never ever once flagged for a mod or a post?

Comment: @random, I mean recently not?. It may be three four month back I had flag but not remember exactly when and to whom and why?. and also wants to know if i flag it three four month back than why this awarded now why not same time?

Comment: I have exactly the same "problem". I earned a Citizen Patrol badge on StackOverflow today... I never flagged a post.

Comment: @Grace Note, Yes you are right it's duplicate. But you are sure about answer of this should be same?

Comment: @mahesh I'm not *sure*. But we are equally unsure that they'll be different. Rather than have everyone accumulate all of their "I got Citizen Patrol without flagging!" posts separately, we serve better to, for now, consolidate them all. Ideally, all reasons discovered will translate to explaining everyone's.

Comment: @Grace Note, I am totally agree with you but where is the answer of my question?. I go through suggested link but still i am confuse what is the reason?. can you provide me exact link?. to know better.

Comment: In this scenario, there is no answer yet.